# Find children of children of a gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab in scene and I want to access a child of that prefab, Structure of that prefab is like this:

```
PauseMenu
    UI_Resume
        TextField
        TextField2
            UI_Side_Back  <---- (I need this child)
    UI_Home
```

`transform.FindChild` return just first level child and `loop` in that transform is loop in first level child too:

```
foreach (Transform item in PooledPause.transform) {
        Debug.Log(item.name);
}
```

I think it's need to be a recursive method or something. How can I find that child?

Comment: "Finding" and knowing the exact path to your object are different things. What you want is a reference to a known path.

Comment: @Hossen Rashno It's what I think and it's also fact. This site relies on answers that match the question be it 5 minutes or 5 decades ago it makes no difference. This page is still relevant and still indexed by search engines. Anyone who is searching for "Finding" children in children will not get help here, because your question isn't actually about finding, it's about making a reference to a known element. Drop the attitude just because someone has pointed out a correction or a flaw.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a path to find a transform:

```
 var target = transform.Find("UI_Resume/TextField2/UI_Side_Back");
```

From the [documentation for `Transform.Find`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html):

> If name contains a '/' character it will traverse the hierarchy like a path name.

Comment: Thank you, It's way better than recursive loop

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way of using wildcards such as "*/child" when you don't know where exactly the child is. Recursive seems to be the way in that specific case.

Answer (score 8):

The "RecursiveChildFind" above does not work, as it will only search one child, not all of them. A working version is below:

```
Transform RecursiveFindChild(Transform parent, string childName)
{
    foreach (Transform child in parent)
    {
        if(child.name == childName)
        {
            return child;
        }
        else
        {
            Transform found = RecursiveFindChild(child, childName);
            if (found != null)
            {
                    return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is yet another solution that let's you **find children in any depth based on any criteria**. It uses a depth-first approach. I therefore recommend to place objects of interest as high up the tree as possible to save some operations.

It is used like this: `parent.FindRecursive("child");`

Or if you need more flexibility: `parent.FindRecursive(child => child.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>() != null && child.name.Contains("!"));`

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static Transform FindRecursive(this Transform self, string exactName) => self.FindRecursive(child => child.name == exactName);

    public static Transform FindRecursive(this Transform self, Func<Transform, bool> selector)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in self)
        {
            if (selector(child))
            {
                return child;
            }

            var finding = child.FindRecursive(selector);

            if (finding != null)
            {
                return finding;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried all the solution but none worked for me. Using the Unity `Find` not worked because I don't know the name of the parent of my child. The recursive solution here only work if you have parent with only one child, what isn't my case too. So, I create the following generic recursive finder that work in any type of `GameObject` hierarch (or tree).

```
public static Transform RecursiveFindChild(Transform parent, string childName)
{
    Transform child = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.childCount; i++)
    {
        child = parent.GetChild(i);
        if (child.name == childName)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            child = RecursiveFindChild(child, childName);
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return child;
}
```

**Note**: use that carefully, avoid big `GameObject` trees.

Answer (score 1):

I don't develop for Unity3D sometime ago but I recommend you to set a tag to your object and search it by the tag. Like [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/893966/how-to-find-child-with-tag.html):

```
  public static T FindComponentInChildWithTag<T>(this GameObject parent, string tag)where T:Component{
       Transform t = parent.transform;
       foreach(Transform tr in t)
       {
              if(tr.tag == tag)
              {
                   return tr.GetComponent<T>();
              }
              else
              {
                   tr.GetComponent<T>().FindComponentInChildWithTag(tag);
              }
       }
  }
```

Or like [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/285133/find-child-of-a-game-object-using-tag.html).

But if you really want to search by the name you can change the previous code to something like [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/183649/how-to-find-a-child-gameobject-by-name.html):

```
if(tr.name == "object name")
```

Or to do a find() like this:

```
tr.Find("Bone");

//or

parent.Find("UI_Resume/TextField2/UI_Side_Back");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `Dan Puzey` for answer, Also if you want to have recursive loop on your object, you can implement that like this:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject theChild = RecursiveFindChild (theParentGameObject.transform, "The Child Name You Want");
}

GameObject RecursiveFindChild(Transform parent, string childName)
{
    foreach (Transform child in parent) {
        if(child.name == childName)
            return child.gameObject;
        else 
            return RecursiveFindChild(child, childName);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is okay, but it is better if you put the name of the object you are looking as parameter of the method. Thanks to this it will be more generic, and can be used in other places of this project or others.

Comment: I don't think this will work. The foreach loop will always return on the first item.

Answer (score 1):

try this **Recursive** method.

```
public static Transform RecursiveFindChild(Transform parent, string childName)
{
    Transform result = null;

    foreach (Transform child in parent)
    {
        if (child.name == childName)
            result = child.transform;
        else
            result = RecursiveFindChild(child, childName);

        if (result != null) break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this if you don't know what the name of the parent may be is to use this :

```
Transform GetChildWithName(GameObject go, string childName)
{
    Transform child = null;
    foreach (Transform t in go.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
    {
        if (t.name == childName)
        {
            child = t;
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
```

Comment: One thing to take into account is that if the parent (go) has the same name as the childName it will return the parent. To avoid that just add a check if it is different than the parent

Answer (score 0):

May as well throw in my version.
How to find Child Child by name.

Not update loop friendly.

```
public GameObject FindChildGameObjectByName(GameObject go, string gameObjectName)
{
    GameObject retrunGO = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < go.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        if (go.transform.GetChild(i).name == gameObjectName)
        {
            retrunGO = go.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        }

        GameObject tmp = FindChildGameObjectByName(go.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject, gameObjectName);

        retrunGO = (tmp != null ? tmp : retrunGO);
    }

    return retrunGO;
}
```