# How to get child object child gameobject in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have one doubt, how to get Child object child. I have one parent Gameobject name `bed_1` that parent have four child object in that four child object one child have another 5 child how to get that 5 child!

Detailed Image:

[image]

Comment: As soon as possible you should've Googled first [for already existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437244/find-children-of-children-of-a-gameobject)

Comment: I need to get child from runtime model.

Comment: @AbbasJ what is a runtime model? and what is wrong with e.g. the suggested `yourModel.Find("pillow")` ?

Comment: Runtime model means i will upload anymodel from resource folder at runtime. So once i uploaded i need to get that model child object child that means i my Prefab model side GetChild(3).gameobject is main i need to get that gameobject child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transform.GetChild(3).GetChild(4)
```

If you do this, I recommend null-checking.

See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html

However, I could recommend you to create a variable:

```
public Transform TargetChild5;
```

And then assign the value by dragging the 5th child into the slot in your script (in inspector)

Comment: GameObject chil4 = selectedObject.transform.GetChild(3).GetChild(3).gameObject; i get child used this line. but i have one more if my model have lot of child means how i can get that Gameobject deatils..